# Notepad++ opening offscreen

Tags: notepad++

Lately, I've been having more and more occurrences of this happening, and I've been unable to resolve it on my own, so hoping perhaps somebody here has any options :)

Notepad++  (v6.6.9)

Running on Windows 10 (v10.0.14393 Build 14393)

Laptop is HP EliteBook 840 G3

I work from office location (dual monitor, laptop lid closed), and at home (laptop screen + 1 monitor)

And the back and forth appears to be confusing the heck out of Notepad++

Each morning I'll boot up, and open Notepad++, and it'll be "off screen" .. it's open, but not visible.

I've tried the "Windows key"+"arrow key"  trick (which works with every other window, however, for some reason, doesn't work with Notepad++)

I've tried to position Notepad++ to the "main" screen just before logging off ... no such luck (probably doesn't help that the "main screen" is different between the 2 locations :)

And checking in the Notepad++ settings, I don't see anything in the Settings => Preferences that would help.

I've checked the config.xml .. it's showing:

```
   <GUIConfig name="RememberLastSession">no</GUIConfig>
```

so I'm not sure why it keeps doing this.

The only way I've been able to get the window is the "old school":

Make sure Notepad++ has focus.
tap Alt, then Left Arrow, Then Down arrow twice, and Enter to select "move". Then tap any arrow key, and then move the mouse, and it'll jump onto the screen at mouse location.

Anyone have any other ideas what's going on? and how to "fix" this ?

Comment: If you move the Notepad++ window to a good position then close by pressing the `X` icon **whilst** holding down `SHIFT` key, does a re-load now have it in the same good position?

Comment: @VC.One: no different than closing it normally .. *shrug* :(  It seems to open in same location .. but next day, (when dual screens are different config) it'll be off screen.

Answer (score 19):

`Windows Key + Shift + Right/Left arrow` will move a window from one monitor to another (Not just the Windows Key). See if that works. I had this problem with other apps before too and that solved it for me.

Also once you get it to the right monitor, it may still be slightly off-screen still. Do `Windows Key + Up arrow` to maximize it.

Comment: nice, learn a new trick every day :)   I'll try that next chance I have (probably tonight) .. :)

Comment: Ok yeah, mostly worked, but no real different than the alt-move trick already .. so I consider this a viable "work around" .. so I'll upvote you for that .. however, I'm going to hold out for an actual "root cause solution" if possible :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The other answers provide workable general solutions. 
This following hack worked for me; it was for Notepad++ but ought to work for other apps.

Open `~\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++\config.xml`

Find the line with `<GUIConfig name="AppPosition"` ...

Change the `x=` and `y=` to something more reasonable.

In my case the off-screen window had negative coordinates so the fix was obvious.
If you're the tidy sort, resize the window to something you like then exit; that's the way it will come back.

Comment: For the 'find all in file' window you need to change x and y in FloatingWindow. I closed notepad++, used another editor to put FloatingWindow x and y to 0 and then reopened notepad++. I don't know if you really need to use another editor but that is what I did.

Comment: Indeed a value in X and Y was negatives. I put X and Y to 100 and it works!

Comment: I tried thousend of different solutions, only this one helped

Answer (score 2):

There is already some workaround as mentioned by @Kevin. This is one of the similar cases as mentioned in the question.

### Problem

After you disable multiple display support, some programs may be displayed off the screen.

**Cause**

This behavior can occur if the program was displayed on a monitor other than the primary monitor before you disabled multiple display support.

**Resolution**

To resolve this issue, use any of the following methods:

**Method 1**

```
* Start the program.
* Right-click the program on the taskbar, and then click Maximize.
* Right-click a blank area of the taskbar, and then click Cascade Windows.
* Resize the program's window as appropriate.
```

**Method 2**

```
* Start the program.
* Right-click the program on the taskbar, and then click Move.
* Move the mouse pointer to the middle of the screen.
* Use the ARROW keys on the keyboard to move the program window to a viewable area on the screen.
* Press ENTER.
* Resize the window if necessary.
```

**Method 3**

**NOTE**: The following method does not apply if you have removed the secondary display adapter from the computer.

```
* Click Start, point to Programs, click Control Panel, and then double- click Display.
* Click the Settings tab.
* In the Display box, click the secondary display adapter.
* Click the "Extend my Windows desktop onto this monitor" checkbox to clear it, and then click OK.
```

**More Information**

This behavior can also occur if you change the arrangement of the monitors on the Settings tab in Display properties.

Content from [this page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/181691/some-programs-are-displayed-off-the-screen) is included in this answer.

I hope this might help. Cheers!

Comment: I've seen a lot of the "right click on taskbar" options .. but I'm on windows 10, and right clicking on the item on taskbar doesn't bring up any menu with "move, maximize, etc" on it .. just "pinned, recent and close" as well as MRU list .. :(

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this after quite sometime browsing through multiple threads on here - hope it's to some use for someone out there.

I'm use **Git Bash** on **Windows 10**, and I had the exact same issue. Two monitors at work, one at home. No matter how many times I used the **'move + arrow keys'** trick and placed the terminal on my main monitor before shutting down my pc, it would still reappear on the 'second' monitor.

So, the trick I found was, that after having used the **'move + arrow keys'** trick, I opened up the properties tab for my terminal, by right clicking on the top bar of my terminal.

From here, I went into the **Layout** tab, and played around with centering my terminal vertically and horizontally usig the numeric input fields.

After this I found what I believe to be the key to this solution.

Make sure that the option for **'Let system position window'** is left unchecked, and what you're left with - hopefully - is a terminal that'll never open on the 'second' monitor ever again!

Again, hope this was usefull and can help someone out there with the similar problem!

Answer (score 0):

**Fix notepad ++ off screen issue (Tested in win10)**

1)First open notepad ++ with any text file and minimize it.

2)Open any other program and take it to left corner till it say for multitasking option (half screen mode).

3)On the next half screen it will show recent apps which is open then click on the notepad ++ it will open that app in the rest of the screen.

Done!!

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows 10 pro.

After I started Slack screen share, my NotePad++ MDI did not show child window in tab properly.

My fix is to close NotePad++, close Slack, use System Internal ProcessExplorer to find and terminate all running Slack processes.
Start NotePad++ again, it runs as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I found that if you unlock your Windows taskbar and shift it to the side, you can find the search results window and move it into the accessible part of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Open the programa, while the focus is on it´s icon on taskbar press "Alt+Space", the menu will open and you can move or maximize.